# annotation bars in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, bar-chart

In ggplot2 I want to plot annotation bars such that the order of the bar color matches other column. [See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRdBU.png). Here for bar "A" colors are according to column y (True or False) and same for bar "B". I tried following but it doe't work.

```
> (df <- data.frame(x=rep(1:5, 2), y=rep(c(T,F), 5), z=c(rep("A",5), rep("B",5))))
   x     y z
1  1  TRUE A
2  2 FALSE A
3  3  TRUE A
4  4 FALSE A
5  5  TRUE A
6  1 FALSE B
7  2  TRUE B
8  3 FALSE B
9  4  TRUE B
10 5 FALSE B
> ggplot(data=df, aes(x=z, y=x, fill=y)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")+ coord_flip()
```

Comment: It's not clear what is the result you're expecting. But the order of colors is determined by their order as factor levels.

Comment: @felasa Please have a look at the image attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `geom_tile` instead. http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_tile.html

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=z, y=x, fill=y)) +  
 geom_tile(stat="identity",width=0.5)+ coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: this is what I am looking for but is it possible to have some space between A & B so that it will look more line a barplot.

Comment: @cNinja - Sure, there's a `width` argument to `geom_tile`

Comment: There's also a `height` argument so you don't need to `coord_flip`.